# What Unix commands can be used as a semaphore/lock?

Tags: scripting, bash, semaphore

I want to run multiple Bash shell scripts in parallel. However, I want to avoid race conditions. What Unix commands are *truly* atomic that I could use for this purpose, and how can I use them?

Comment: What are you doing that requires parallel work? Can't you express the dependencies in a way that allows a parallel `make(1)` to take over? (i.e., do a `make -j 9` if you have 8 cores)? This has the added advantage of interleaving work with finer granularity.

Comment: See also [Quick-and-dirty way to ensure only one instance of a shell script is running at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870221/is-there-any-mutex-semaphore-mechanism-in-shell-scripts

Comment: [The Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/locking.html#inode-operations) lists system calls (of file-system commands) applying semaphore as locking mechanism (see `inode_operations` section).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If `lockfile` is not installed on your system, then `mkdir` will do
the work: it's an atomic operation, and it fails if the directory 
already exists (as long as you don't add the `-p` command-line
switch).

```
create_lock_or_wait () {
  path="$1"
  wait_time="${2:-10}"
  while true; do
        if mkdir "${path}.lock.d"; then
           break;
        fi
        sleep $wait_time
  done
}

remove_lock () {
  path="$1"
  rmdir "${path}.lock.d"
}
```

Comment: 10 years late, but the correct answer then, and now ,is flock, discussed below (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291/343121)

Answer (score 39):

[`flock(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Makes sure we exit if flock fails.
set -e

(
  # Wait for lock on /var/lock/.myscript.exclusivelock (fd 200) for 10 seconds
  flock -x -w 10 200

  # Do stuff

) 200>/var/lock/.myscript.exclusivelock
```

This ensures that code between "(" and ")" is run only by one process at a time and that the process does wait for a lock too long.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about it.  However, it's apparently Linux-specific...

Comment: @Riccardo, FreeBSD has a similar command: `lockf(1)`.

Comment: `lockf(1)` doesn't work in the way used in this example, though. It can't take a file descriptor number as an argument.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri `brew install discoteq/discoteq/flock`

Comment: Shorter but equivalent: `flock -w 10 /var/lock/.myscript.exclusivelock -c '# do stuff'`. No need for `( ... ) 200> ...` if you only execute a few simple commands. However, if you want to modify the environment (for instance, assign a variable inside the lock for later use) then use `{ ... } 200> ...`.

Comment: this is the correct answer - flock is available on all linux distros and as @HappyFace commented, available as ok'ish port for bsd

Comment: Reading the man page I can't find the reason why it's specifically "200" ? What does 200 means ? I know that 10 is the number of the seconds to wait before failing

Comment: Also I just tested and if the script is killed with -9 then the script can never run again, unless you manually remove the lock ?

Answer (score 12):

lockfile(1) looks like a good candidate, though beware that it's part of the [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) package, which you may not have installed on your machine yet.  It's a popular enough package that it should be packaged for your system if it's not installed yet.  Three of the four systems I checked have it, and the other has it available.

Using it is simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOCKFILE=$HOME/.myscript/lock
mkdir -p `dirname $LOCKFILE`

echo Waiting for lock $LOCKFILE...
if lockfile -1 -r15 $LOCKFILE
then
    # Do protected stuff here
    echo Doing protected stuff...

    # Then, afterward, clean up so another instance of this script can run
    rm -f $LOCKFILE
else
    echo "Failed to acquire lock!  lockfile(1) returned $?"
    exit 1
fi
```

The options I've given make it retry once a second for up to 15 seconds.  Drop the "-r" flag if you want it to wait forever.

Comment: Just for reference - the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile. :)

Comment: Be aware that (according to the manpage), "Once a file is locked, the lock must be touched at least once every five minutes or the lock will be considered stale, and subsequent lock attempts will succeed."

Answer (score 9):

The system call `mkdir()` is atomic on POSIX filesystems.  So, using the `mkdir` command in such a way that it involves exactly one call to `mkdir()` would achieve your purpose.  (IOW, don't use `mkdir -p`).  The corresponding unlock is `rmdir` of course.

Caveat emptor: `mkdir()` might not be atomic on network filesystems.

Comment: is `rmdir` therefore also atomic?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the lockfile command will do what you need.

```
lockfile ~/.config/mylockfile.lock
.....
rm -f important.lock
```

Comment: This seems to delete the wrong file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only running on Unix, use fifos. You can write work records to the fifo and have processes read from this file and your readers will block on the fifos.

Lock files are ok, but for what you describe I would go with fifos

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you think fifos can prevent race conditions?

Answer (score 1):

As posted here: " [Correct locking in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts/126398#126398) ", using [FLOM (Free LOck Manager)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flom/) tool, serializing commands and shell scripts becomes as easy as running

```
flom -- command_to_serialize
```

FLOM allows you to implement more sofisticate use cases (distributed locking, readers/writers, numeric resources, etc...) as explained here: http://sourceforge.net/p/flom/wiki/FLOM%20by%20examples/