# Correct locking in shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script, cron, nfs, coreutils, lock

Sometimes you have to make sure that only one instance of a shell script is running at the same time.

For example a cron job which is executed via crond that does not provide
locking on its own (e.g. the default Solaris crond).

A common pattern to implement locking is code like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOCK=/var/tmp/mylock
if [ -f $LOCK ]; then            # 'test' -> race begin
  echo Job is already running\!
  exit 6
fi
touch $LOCK                      # 'set'  -> race end
# do some work
rm $LOCK
```

Of course, such code has a race condition. There is a time window where the
execution of two instances can both advance after line 3 before one is able to
touch the `$LOCK` file.

For a cron job this is usually not a problem because you have an interval of
minutes between two invocations.

But things can go wrong - for example when the lockfile is on a NFS server -
that hangs. In that case several cron jobs can block on line 3 and queue up. If
the NFS server is active again then you have [thundering herd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) of parallel
running jobs.

Searching on the web I found the tool [lockrun](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.html) which seems like a good
solution to that problem. With it you run a script that needs locking like
this:

```
$ lockrun --lockfile=/var/tmp/mylock myscript.sh
```

You can put this in a wrapper or use it from your crontab.

It uses `lockf()` (POSIX) if available and falls back to `flock()` (BSD). And `lockf()` support over NFS should be relatively widespread.

Are there alternatives to `lockrun`?

What about other cron daemons? Are there common crond's that support locking in a
sane way? A quick look into the man page of Vixie Crond (default on
Debian/Ubuntu systems) does not show anything about locking.

Would it be a good idea to include a tool like `lockrun` into [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)?

In my opinion it implements a theme very similar to [`timeout`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation), `nice` and friends.

Comment: Tangentially, and for the benefit of others who may consider your initial pattern Good Enough(tm), that shell code should possibly trap TERM in order to remove its lockfile when `kill`ed; and it seems to be good practice to store one's own pid in the lockfile, rather than just touching it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Unix commands can be used as a semaphore/lock?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-unix-commands-can-be-used-as-a-semaphore-lock)

Comment: @Shawn, not really, does not mention crond and NFS.

Comment: related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at-a

Comment: @Ulrich very belatedly, storing a PID in an NFS lockfile adds very little value. Even adding the hostname still doesn't really help with checking for a live process

Comment: I've created the [tool `lockf`](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility) that supports various locking methods (lockf, fcntl, flock, rename, ...). Perhaps useful for testing the different methods in heterogeneous environments.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's another way to do locking in shell script that can prevent the race condition you describe above, where two jobs may both pass line 3.  The `noclobber` option will work in ksh and bash.  Don't use `set noclobber` because you shouldn't be scripting in csh/tcsh. ;)

```
lockfile=/var/tmp/mylock

if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then

        trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

        # do stuff here

        # clean up after yourself, and release your trap
        rm -f "$lockfile"
        trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
        echo "Lock Exists: $lockfile owned by $(cat $lockfile)"
fi
```

YMMV with locking on NFS (you know, when NFS servers are not reachable), but in general it's much more robust than it used to be. (10 years ago)

If you have cron jobs that do the same thing at the same time, from multiple servers, but you only need 1 instance to actually run, the something like this might work for you.

I have no experience with lockrun, but having a pre-set lock environment prior to the script actually running might help.  Or it might not.  You're just setting the test for the lockfile outside your script in a wrapper, and theoretically, couldn't you just hit the same race condition if two jobs were called by lockrun at exactly the same time, just as with the 'inside-the-script' solution?

File locking is pretty much honor system behavior anyways, and any scripts that don't check for the lockfile's existence prior to running will do whatever they're going to do.  Just by putting in the lockfile test, and proper behavior, you'll be solving 99% of potential problems, if not 100%.

If you run into lockfile race conditions a lot, it may be an indicator of a larger problem, like not having your jobs timed right, or perhaps if interval is not as important as the job completing, maybe your job is better suited to be daemonized.

---

#### EDIT BELOW - 2016-05-06 (if you're using KSH88)

---

Base on @Clint Pachl's comment below, if you use ksh88, use `mkdir` instead of `noclobber`.  This mostly mitigates a potential race condition, but doesn't entirely limit it (though the risk is miniscule).  For more information read [the link that Clint posted below](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045).

```
lockdir=/var/tmp/mylock
pidfile=/var/tmp/mylock/pid

if ( mkdir ${lockdir} ) 2> /dev/null; then
        echo $$ > $pidfile
        trap 'rm -rf "$lockdir"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
        # do stuff here

        # clean up after yourself, and release your trap
        rm -rf "$lockdir"
        trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
        echo "Lock Exists: $lockdir owned by $(cat $pidfile)"
fi
```

And, as an added advantage, if you need to create tmpfiles in your script, you can use the `lockdir` directory for them, knowing they will be cleaned up when the script exits.

For more modern bash, the noclobber method at the top should be suitable.

Comment: No, with lockrun you don't have a problem - when a NFS server hangs, all lockrun calls will hang (at least) in the `lockf()` system call - when it is back up all processes are resumed but only one process will win the lock. No race condition. I don't run into such problems with cronjobs a lot - the opposite is the case - but this is a problem when it hits you it has the potential to create a lot of pain.

Comment: Your noclobber method seems to be safe: http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_d10 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045#Discussion

Comment: I have accepted this answer because the method is safe and so far the most elegant one. I suggest a small variant: `set -o noclobber && echo "$$" > "$lockfile"` to get a safe fallback when the shell does not support the noclobber option.

Comment: Good answer, but you should also 'kill -0' the value in lockfile to ensure that the process that created the lock still exists.

Comment: I was going to agree with @maxschlepzig about this being a bashism, but it turns out to work in `dash` (and `zsh`). I haven't tried any of the "bashism testers."  Still, I disagree with this approach on [deep magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_magic) grounds; it's obscure and hard to read for people who don't know what it does.  Better to go with `[ ! -e "$lockfile" ] && echo $$ > "$lockfile" 2>/dev/null` for legibility.

Comment: @AdamKatz, that introduces an obvious race condition. A lot can happen between checking the lock file and writing/locking it. Setting the `noclobber` option **may** be atomic, but one would have to check the shell implementation to make sure `open` uses the `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` options **and** that the OS supports advisory locking.

Comment: The `noclobber` option may be prone to race conditions. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045 for some food for thought.

Comment: @ClintPachl : Thanks.  Interesting reading.  I like the solution of using a directory, then creating temp files in that directory, which gets cleaned up automatically.

Comment: @NigelHorne makes a good point, but the existence of a process withthe appropriate PID isn't enough.  The cmdline associated with that PID should also match the current one.

Comment: Note: using `noclobber` (or `-C`) in ksh88 does not work because ksh88 does not use `O_EXCL` for `noclobber`.  If you're running with a newer shell you may be OK...

Comment: Tim, the page Clint linked only mentions that noclobber isn't sufficient with ksh88. Which is arguably a niche shell, nowadays. In any case, mkdir seems to have more serious limitations - cf. the links Gilles provided in a comment to Glenn's mkdir answer.

Comment: Thanks @maxschlepzig.  I've updated the edit to specifcally refer to ksh88.

Comment: isn't `/var/tmp` a bad place to store lock files, since they are preserved across reboots. I don't think a process will be preserved across a reboot. So you would want a place that is explicitly cleared on reboots? Also some systems clean files in /var/tmp after 30days of non use. Something like /var/lock would make more sense?

Answer (score 18):

I prefer to use hard links.

```
lockfile=/var/lock/mylock
tmpfile=${lockfile}.$$
echo $$ > $tmpfile
if ln $tmpfile $lockfile 2>&-; then
    echo locked
else
    echo locked by $(<$lockfile)
    rm $tmpfile
    exit
fi
trap "rm ${tmpfile} ${lockfile}" 0 1 2 3 15
# do what you need to
```

[Hard links are atomic over NFS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#82521) and for the most part, [mkdir is as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk/Archives/Computing/2009_April_2#Atomic_operations_on_NFS).  Using `mkdir(2)` or `link(2)` are about the same, at a practical level; I just prefer using hard links because more implementations of NFS allowed atomic hard links than atomic `mkdir`. With modern releases of NFS, you shouldn't have to worry using either.

Comment: What deos 2>&- do?

Comment: The `&-` can be used to close the file descriptor.  In this case, it suppresses error messages from `ln` as we are only concerned with its exit code.

Answer (score 14):

I understand that `mkdir` is atomic, so perhaps:

```
lockdir=/var/tmp/myapp
if mkdir $lockdir; then
  # this is a new instance, store the pid
  echo $$ > $lockdir/PID
else
  echo Job is already running, pid $(<$lockdir/PID) >&2
  exit 6
fi

# then set traps to cleanup upon script termination 
# ref http://www.shelldorado.com/goodcoding/tempfiles.html
trap 'rm -r "$lockdir" >/dev/null 2>&1' 0
trap "exit 2" 1 2 3 13 15
```

Comment: Ok, but I could not find informations whether `mkdir()` over NFS (>=3) is standardized to be atomic.

Comment: @maxschlepzig [RFC 1813](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1813.txt) does not explicitly call out for `mkdir` to be atomic (it does for `rename`). In practice, it is [known](http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg20456.html) that some implementations are not. Related: [an interesting thread, including a contribution by the author of GNU arch](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1035100).

Answer (score 12):

`sem` which comes as part of the GNU `parallel` tools may be what you're looking for:

```
sem [--fg] [--id <id>] [--semaphoretimeout <secs>] [-j <num>] [--wait] command
```

As in:

```
sem --id my_semaphore --fg "echo 1 ; date ; sleep 3" &
sem --id my_semaphore --fg "echo 2 ; date ; sleep 3" &
sem --id my_semaphore --fg "echo 3 ; date ; sleep 3" &
```

outputting:

```
1
Thu 10 Nov 00:26:21 UTC 2016
2
Thu 10 Nov 00:26:24 UTC 2016
3
Thu 10 Nov 00:26:28 UTC 2016
```

Note that order isn't guaranteed. Also the output isn't displayed until it finishes (irritating!). But even so, it's the most concise way I know to guard against concurrent execution, without worrying about lockfiles and retries and cleanup.

Comment: Does the locking offered by `sem` handle being shot down mid-execution?

Comment: Regarding *"the output isn't displayed until it finishes"*: You can disable the buffering using `-u` or `--lb`, see `man parallel`.

Comment: @roaima Yes, `sem` seems to correctly handle shutdowns like ctrl+c and even a brutal `kill -9` (`SIGKILL`). You can try this using `timeout -s9 1 sem -u --id myid --fg 'echo a; sleep 3; echo b'; sem -u --id myid --fg 'echo c'`. For a better test, run this check in a loop and vary the timeout. In each iteration a `c` should be printed. Endless test: `shuf -re {00..40} | while read t; do printf a; timeout -s9 0.$t sem -u --id myid --fg 'sleep 0.2; printf b'; sem -u --id myid --fg 'printf c'; echo d; done | grep '[^c]d'`. No output means everything works fine.

Answer (score 11):

An easy way is to use [`lockfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile) coming usually with the `procmail` package.

```
LOCKFILE="/tmp/mylockfile.lock"
# try once to get the lock else exit
lockfile -r 0 "$LOCKFILE" || exit 0

# here the actual job

rm -f "$LOCKFILE"
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the command-line tool `flock` to manage locks in my bash scripts, as described [here](http://jdimpson.livejournal.com/5685.html) and [here](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030616.html). It is included in the Debian package `util-linux` and is installed by default on many Linux systems.

Here's how you would use it for a cron job:

```
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/foobar /usr/bin/foobar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This would create the file `/tmp/foobar` if it does not exist already, attempt to obtain an exclusive lock on that file, run `/usr/bin/foobar arg1 arg2 arg3`, and then release that lock, exiting with the exit code of the command. If the lock cannot be obtained, then the `flock` command fails immediately with a 1 exit code, because of the `-n` option (short for `--non-block`).

I have used this simple method from the flock manpage, to run some commands in a subshell...

```
   (
     flock -n 9
     # ... commands executed under lock ...
   ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

In that example, it fails with exit code of 1 if it can't acquire the lockfile.

Comment: The `flock()` system call [does not work over NFS](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock).

Comment: BSD has a similar tool, "lockf".

Comment: @dubiousjim, [BSD lockf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lockf) also calls `flock()` and is thus problematic over NFS. Btw, in the meantime, flock() on Linux now falls back to `fcntl()` when the file is located on a NFS mount, thus, in a Linux-only NFS environment `flock()` now does work over NFS.

Comment: `flock` is part of the `util-linux` package on Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I use [`dtach`](http://dtach.sf.net/).

```
$ dtach -n /tmp/socket long_running_task ; echo $?
0
$ dtach -n /tmp/socket long_running_task ; echo $?
dtach: /tmp/socket: Address already in use
1
```

Answer (score 2):

## For actual use, you should use the [top voted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22047/135943).

However, I want to discuss some various broken and semi-workable approaches using `ps` and the many caveats they have, since I keep seeing people use them.

This answer is really the answer to **"Why not use `ps` and `grep` to handle locking in the shell?"**

### Broken approach #1

First, an approach given in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22072/135943) that has a few upvotes despite the fact that it does not (and could never) work and was clearly never tested:

```
running_proc=$(ps -C bash -o pid=,cmd= | grep my_script);
if [[ "$running_proc" != "$$ bash my_script" ]]; do 
  echo Already locked
  exit 6
fi
```

Let's fix the syntax errors and the broken `ps` arguments and get:

```
running_proc=$(ps -C bash -o pid,cmd | grep "$0");
echo "$running_proc"
if [[ "$running_proc" != "$$ bash $0" ]]; then
  echo Already locked
  exit 6
fi
```

This script will *always* exit 6, every time, no matter how you run it.

If you run it with `./myscript`, then the `ps` output will just be `12345 -bash`, which doesn't match the required string `12345 bash ./myscript`, so that will fail.

If you run it with `bash myscript`, things get more interesting.  The bash process *forks* to run the pipeline, and the *child* shell runs the `ps` and `grep`.  Both the original shell and the child shell will show up in the `ps` output, something like this:

```
25793 bash myscript
25795 bash myscript
```

That's not the expected output `$$ bash $0`, so your script will exit.

### Broken approach #2

Now in all fairness to the user who wrote broken approach #1, I did something similar myself when I first tried this:

```
if otherpids="$(pgrep -f "$0" | grep -vFx "$$")" ; then
  echo >&2 "There are other copies of the script running; exiting."
  ps >&2 -fq "${otherpids//$'\n'/ }" # -q takes about a tenth the time as -p
  exit 1
fi
```

This *almost* works.  But the fact of forking to run the pipe throws this off.  So this one will always exit, also.

### Unreliable approach #3

```
pids_this_script="$(pgrep -f "$0")"
if not_this_process="$(echo "$pids_this_script" | grep -vFx "$$")"; then
  echo >&2 "There are other copies of this script running; exiting."
  ps -fq "${not_this_process//$'\n'/ }"
  exit 1
fi
```

This version avoids the pipeline forking problem in approach #2 by first getting all PIDs that have the current script in their command line arguments, and *then* filtering that pidlist, separately, to omit the PID of the current script.

This might work...providing no other process has a command line matching the `$0`, and providing the script is always called the same way (e.g. if it's called with a relative path and then an absolute path, the latter instance will not notice the former).

### Unreliable approach #4

So what if we skip checking the full command line, since that might not indicate a script actually running, and check `lsof` instead to find all the processes that have this script open?

Well, yes, this approach is actually not too bad:

```
if otherpids="$(lsof -t "$0" | grep -vFx "$$")"; then
  echo >&2 "Error: There are other processes that have this script open - most likely other copies of the script running.  Exiting to avoid conflicts."
  ps >&2 -fq "${otherpids//$'\n'/ }"
  exit 1
fi
```

Of course, if a *copy* of the script is running, then the new instance will start up just fine and you'll have two *copies* running.

Or if the running script is modified (e.g. with Vim or with a `git checkout`), then the "new" version of the script will start up with no problem, since both Vim and `git checkout` result in a new file (a new inode) in place of the old one.

However, **if the script is never modified and never copied,** then this version is pretty good.  There's no race condition because the script file already has to be open before the check can be reached.

There can still be false positives if another process has the script file open, but note that even if it's open for editing in Vim, vim doesn't actually hold the script file open so won't result in false positives.

But remember, don't use this approach if the script might be edited or copied since you'll get false *negatives* i.e. multiple instances running at once - so the fact that editing with Vim doesn't give false positives kind of shouldn't matter to you.  I mention it, though, because approach #3 *does* give false positives (i.e. refuses to start) if you have the script open with Vim.

### So what to do, then?

The [top-voted answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22047/135943) gives a good solid approach.

Perhaps you can write a better one...but if you don't understand all the problems and caveats with all the above approaches, you're not likely to write a locking method that avoids them all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a file.

If your script is executed like this e.g.:

```
bash my_script
```

You can detect if it's running using:

```
running_proc=$(ps -C bash -o pid=,cmd= | grep my_script);
if [[ "$running_proc" != "$$ bash my_script" ]]; do 
  echo Already locked
  exit 6
fi
```

Comment: Hm, the ps checking code runs from within `my_script`? In the case another instance is running - does not `running_proc` contain two matching lines? I like the idea, but of course - you will get false results when another user is running a script with the same name ...

Comment: It also includes a race condition: if 2 instances execute the first line in parallel then none gets the 'lock' and both exit with status 6. This would be a kind of one round mutual [starvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation). Btw, I am not sure why you use `$!` instead of `$$` in your example.

Comment: @maxschlepzig indeed sorry about the incorrect $! vs. $$

Comment: @maxschlepzig to handle multiple users running the script add euser= to the -o argument.

Comment: @maxschlepzig to prevent multiple lines you can also change the arguments to grep, or additional "filters"  (e.g. `grep -v $$`). Basically I was attempting to provide a different approach to the problem.

Comment: This has basic syntax errors demonstrating it was never tested.  Even if the syntax errors are fixed, it will never work under any circumstances.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485825/135943

Answer (score 0):

Using [FLOM (Free LOck Manager)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flom/) tool, serializing commands becomes as easy as running

```
flom -- command_to_serialize
```

FLOM allows you to implement more sofisticate use cases (distributed locking, readers/writers, numeric resources, etc...) as explained here: http://sourceforge.net/p/flom/wiki/FLOM%20by%20examples/

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I sometimes add on a server to easily handle race conditions for any job's  on the machine. 
It is simmilar to Tim Kennedy's post, but this way you get race handling by only adding one row to each bash script that needs it.

Put the content below  in e.g /opt/racechecker/racechecker     :

```
ZPROGRAMNAME=$(readlink -f $0)
EZPROGRAMNAME=`echo $ZPROGRAMNAME | sed 's/\//_/g'`
EZMAIL="/usr/bin/mail"
EZCAT="/bin/cat"

if  [ -n "$EZPROGRAMNAME" ] ;then
        EZPIDFILE=/tmp/$EZPROGRAMNAME.pid
        if [ -e "$EZPIDFILE" ] ;then
                EZPID=$($EZCAT $EZPIDFILE)
                echo "" | $EZMAIL -s "$ZPROGRAMNAME already running with pid $EZPID"  alarms@someemail.com >>/dev/null
                exit -1
        fi
        echo $$ >> $EZPIDFILE
        function finish {
          rm  $EZPIDFILE
        }
        trap finish EXIT
fi
```

Here is how to use it. Note the row after the shebang:

```
     #/bin/bash
     . /opt/racechecker/racechecker
     echo "script are running"
     sleep 120
```

The way it works is that it figures out the main bashscript file name and creates a pidfile under "/tmp". It also  adds a listener to the finish signal. 
The listener will remove the pidfile when the main script are properly finishing.

Instead if a pidfile exist when an instance are launched, then  the if statement containing the code inside the second if-statement  will be executed.  In this  case I have decided to launch an alarm mail when this happens.

**What if the script crashes**

A further exercise would be to handle  crashes. Ideally the pidfile should be removed even if the main-script crashes for any reason, this are not done in my version above. That means if the script crashes the pidfile would have to be manually removed to restore functionality.

**In case of system crash**

It is a good idea to store the pidfile/lockfile under for example /tmp.  This way your scripts  will definently continue to execute after a system crash  since the pidfiles will always be deleted on bootup.

Comment: Unlike Tim Kennedy's ansatz, your script DOES contain a race condition. This is because your checking of the presence of the PIDFILE and its conditional creation is not done in an atomic operation.

Comment: +1 on that! I will take this under consideration and modify my script.

Answer (score -3):

Check my script ...

You may **LOVE** it....

```
[rambabu@Server01 ~]$ sh Prevent_cron-OR-Script_against_parallel_run.sh
Parallel RUN Enabled
Now running
Task completed in Parallel RUN...
[rambabu@Server01 ~]$ cat Prevent_cron-OR-Script_against_parallel_run.sh
#!/bin/bash
#Created by RambabuKella
#Date : 12-12-2013

#LOCK file name
Parallel_RUN="yes"
#Parallel_RUN="no"
PS_GREP=0
LOCK=/var/tmp/mylock_`whoami`_"$0"
#Checking for the process
PS_GREP=`ps -ef |grep "sh $0" |grep -v grep|wc -l`
if [ "$Parallel_RUN" == "no" ] ;then
echo "Parallel RUN Disabled"

 if [ -f $LOCK ] || [ $PS_GREP -gt 2   ] ;then
        echo -e "\nJob is already running OR LOCK file exists. "
        echo -e "\nDetail are : "
        ps -ef |grep  "$0" |grep -v grep
        cat "$LOCK"
  exit 6
 fi
echo -e "LOCK file \" $LOCK \" created on : `date +%F-%H-%M` ." &> $LOCK
# do some work
echo "Now running"
echo "Task completed on with single RUN ..."
#done

rm -v $LOCK 2>/dev/null
exit 0
else

echo "Parallel RUN Enabled"

# do some work
echo "Now running"
echo "Task completed in Parallel RUN..."
#done

exit 0
fi
echo "some thing wrong"
exit 2
[rambabu@Server01 ~]$
```

Answer (score -4):

I offer the following solution, in a script named 'flocktest'

```
#!/bin/bash
export LOGFILE=`basename $0`.logfile
logit () {
echo "$1" >>$LOGFILE
}
PROGPATH=$0
(
flock -x -n 257
(($?)) && logit "'$PROGPATH' is already running!" && exit 0
logit "'$PROGPATH', proc($$): sleeping 30 seconds"
sleep 30
)257<$PROGPATH
```