# NFS file locking not working, am I misunderstanding?

Tags: nfs, lock

I'm planning on having a complicated file sharing setup, and want to make sure I don't destroy file locking.  (Wanting to use bind mounting, nfs, nfs over rdma (InfiniBand file sharing), and virtfs (kvm virtual machine pass-through file sharing) on the same data.)

I'm at the beginning sanity checks, just testing the nfs server with a single nfs client.  Up to date Arch on both systems, nfs-utils 1.3.2-6, kernel 4.1.6-1.

I'm seeing unexpected results.  On the nfs server:

```
server exports with: /test 192.168.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,
   no_root_squash)
client mount shows: 192.168.1.2:/test on /test type nfs4 (rw,noatime,vers=4.2,
   rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,
   retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.3,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.2)
```

In /test, I have a script named `lockFile` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="lockedFile"
exec 200>$filename
flock -n 200 || exit 1
pid=$$
while true; do
   echo $pid 1>&200
done
```

If I use two terminals on the nfs server:

```
1: ./lockFile
2: ./lockFile
```

Then, terminal 1 quickly fills up a file with its pid, and terminal 2 immediately exits.  All as expected.

But, if I run a terminal each on the nfs server and client:

```
server: ./lockFile
client: ./lockFile
```

They both happily run, very unexpected.

In this configuration, my nfs server is running as `sync`, meaning the server only says data is written when it is actually written.  My nfs client is running as `async`, meaning the client only transmits the writes when the file is closed.

I could see the client running `async` perhaps not obtaining a lock until it actually transmits the writes, so I tested this, changing the client to `sync`.

```
client mount now shows: 192.168.1.2:/test on /test type nfs4 (rw,noatime,sync,
   vers=4.2,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,
   retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.3,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.2)
```

Still `lockFile` happily runs on both machines.

Am I misunderstanding how NFS file locking is expected to work?  Is it expected to handle server access vs client access?  Or, is it just for client access vs different client access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flock` doesn't work over NFS. (It never has, even on UNIX systems.)

See [flock vs lockf on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409780/flock-vs-lockf-on-linux) for one comparison of `lockf` and `flock`.

Here is a possible solution [Correct locking in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: You nailed it.  Wrote a c app that uses lockf, and terminal 2 now complains like it should.

Comment: That's not what's here: http://serverfault.com/a/692982/306772 "Since Linux 2.6.12, NFS clients support flock() locks by emulating them as byte-range locks on the entire file."

Comment: @Rodrigo I hear you. However, the solution suggested in your link doesn't work with `flock()`. It does work with `lockf()`. I am running `rpc.statd` with NFS3 on "recent enough" kernels.