# How do I get commands in a bash script to complete? (files get truncated with cp)

Tags: shell-script, cp

- I have a server that receives `backupname.tar.gz` files in `/home/my_user/drop` directory every hour.
- I installed incron utility and use incrontab -e entry to run a script whenever a new file shows up in /drop

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# First clear the 2 immediate use directories
rm /home/my_user/local_ready/*
wait
sleep 1
rm /home/my_user/local_restore/*
wait
sleep1

# Copy the file from the /drop /local_ready
cp /home/my_user/drop/*.tar.gz /home/my_user/local_ready/
wait
sleep 5

# Now move the file to the /current folder
mv /home/my_user/drop/*.tar.gz /home/my_user/current/
wait
sleep 1

# Next we delete any stray files dropped that are not
# of the target type so we can keep /drop clean.
rm /home/my_user/drop/*
wait
sleep 1

# Un-Tar the files into the /local_restore directory
tar -xzf /home/my_user/local_ready/*.tar.gz -C /home/my_user/local_restore/
wait
sleep 1

# This should complete the movement of files
```

The problem I have been running into is the file that gets copied to the `/local_restore` directory is truncated as if the next command in the script is causing an interruption to the `cp` command.

At first I put sleep commands in it to try to get it to work, then I added wait commands after each command in the script to try to get it to work thinking that would force everything to wait until the cp command had finished copying the file to the next location.

I cannot even tell if the `tar` command is working at all because it depends on the success of the `cp` command further up the chain to have the file in place. Based on a test I ran with only a command to un-tar one of the files, I suspect it will not complete either before the script exits either. At least that occurred in a different 3 line test I used to test my timing theory.

BTW... the `mv` command works just fine and the whole file gets moved as it should.

Can anyone identify why the commands run in the script seem to be unable to complete their task?

I have been asked to show the contents of the incrontab entry so here it is:

> /home/my_user/drop/ IN_CREATE /home/my_user/bin/cycle_backups

(cycle_backups is obviously the name of the script file)

This is a KVM type VPS cloud server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it has 10gb of memory with over 100gb of disk space. When the file is dropped, this is the only thing the server has to do other than system idle!

I will admit that my server is a bit slow, so when trying to copy a 200mb file to another directory it takes a second or two to complete even when I do it right at the command line.

I am at a loss to explain the problem, which makes it even harder to identify a solution.

Fair Warning: I am not the best at any of this, but I didn't think this should be such an impossible thing to accomplish.

Comment: The `wait` is pointless and unnecessary. Commands run synchronously in a script unless you explicitly state otherwise.

Comment: Well, if the wait is pointless then why is the cp command unable to complete it's task before the other commands in the script run? Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: When the incrontab entry runs the script, it calls it out with the full path /home/my/_user/bin/cycle_backups  So I'm not sure it matters where /bin/sh points.

Comment: @BKM `wait` is used to wait for background processes to finish before continuing. There's not a single background process in your script, so the `wait`s are pointless, as are all the `sleep`s. And you know that, since the problem existed before you added all those `wait`s and `sleep`s.

Comment: Which mask is used  "whenever a new file shows up in /drop"? Please add the output of `incrontab -l` so we can see how your script is triggered.

Comment: Freddy, The contents of the incrontab entry has been added to the post above.

Comment: Ahh... good point muru. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @BKM change the `IN_CREATE` to `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` as [alecxs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511558/332764) already pointed out. This should trigger the script when the tar.gz was fully written (and not when it was created while being uploaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change mask to IN_CLOSE_WRITE

Comment: script looks fine to me. guess script is started before finished copy (does not concern mv because it only changes file descriptor, but cp runs too early)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by changing the mask. How exactly would I use IN_CLOSE_WRITE to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have created incrontab -e entry? there you set the second word. <path> <mask> <command>

Comment: A new file "showing up in /drop" is not an atomic event. A new file gets created (initially empty), things get written into it over some period of time, and eventually (when everything has been written) the creating process will close it. If this script runs when it's created, the `cp` can run before the file is all there, and will therefore only copy part of it (the part that exists when `cp` runs). Solution: don't run the script until the file has been created *and closed*.

Comment: Thank you all. Ultimately, this was the answer that fixed my problem. By using IN_CREATE in my incrontab statement, the 'cp' command was able to begin execution (before the file was all there) because the act of creating the file in the /drop folder was valid to complete the incron task. The only reason the 'mv' command worked is because it was waiting for the file to finish writing before it would execute. At first I didn't understand IN_CLOSE_WRITE was to go in my incrontab entry so I had to ask what it meant. Several other kind contributors here filled in the blanks. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

None of the calls to `wait` will do anything in your script as there are no background tasks.  You may safely delete these.

I would delete the calls to `sleep` as well.  They will only delay the script execution at those points.  A command will not start until the previous one has properly finished anyway.  Also `sleep1` is likely to generate a "command not found" error.

The only real issue that I can see with your script is the last call to `tar`:

```
tar -xzf /home/my_user/local_ready/*.tar.gz -C /home/my_user/local_restore/
```

If there are multiple archives in `/home/my_user/local_ready`, then this command would extract the first one and try to extract the names of the other archives from that archive.  The `-f` flag takes a *single* archive, and you can't really extract multiple archives at once.

Instead, use a loop:

```
for archive in /home/my_user/local_ready/*.tar.gz; do
    tar -xzf "$archive" -C /home/my_user/local_restore/
done
```

I've *ignored* considerations of what happens if this script is run concurrently with itself.  You mention that you have some facility to execute the script when a new file shows up, but it's unclear what would happen if two or more files showed up at about the same time.  Since the script is handling *all* files in a single invocation, I'm pretty sure that two concurrently running script may well step on each other's toes.

Personally, I might instead run the script on a regular five minute interval.  Alternatively use some form of locking to make sure that the script is not running while another copy of the script is already in progress (see e.g. "[Correct locking in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts)").

Here's my own rewrite of your code (not doing any form of locking):

```
#!/bin/sh -e

cd /home/my_user

# clear directories
rm -f local_ready/*
rm -f local_restore/*

# Alternatively, remove directories completely
# to also get rid of hidden files etc.:
#
#  rm -rf local_ready;   mkdir local_ready
#  rm -rf local_restore; mkdir local_restore

# handle the archives, one by one
for archive in drop/*.tar.gz; do
    tar -xzf "$archive" -C local_restore
    cp "$archive" current
    mv "$archive" local_ready
done
```

This would clear out the directories of non-hidden names and then extract each archive.  Once an archive has been extracted it would be copied to the `local_ready` directory, and then the archive would also be moved from `drop` to `current`.

I'm using `sh -e` to make the script terminate on errors, and I `cd` to the `/home/my_user` directory to avoid having long paths in the script (this also makes it easier to move the whole operation to a subdirectory or elsewhere later).  I'm using `rm -f` for clearing out those directories as `rm` would complain if the `*` glob did not expand to anything.

You could also obviously handle archive copying and extraction separately:

```
cp drop/*.tar.gz current
mv drop/*.tar.gz local_ready

for archive in local_ready/*.tar.gz; do
    tar -xzf "$archive" -C local_restore
done
```

To save space, you may want to look into hard-linking the files in `local_ready` and `current`:

```
mv drop/*.tar.gz local_ready

for archive in local_ready/*.tar.gz; do
    ln "$archive" current
    tar -xzf "$archive" -C local_restore
done
```