# Can a crontab job run concurrently with itself?

Tags: cron

If I have a crontab job that runs, for instance, every hour, but that job may take more than an hour to complete, will the next job fail to run?

Comment: Is your question about a single cron job possibly running longer than the interval set or are you talking about independent cron jobs?

Comment: @gertvdijk: Different instances of the same job. I just wanted to make sure that it would always run, even when the previous instance  is still running.

Comment: Ah okay. Having two instances of the same job running is something you would want to avoid generally, so that's not too obvious from your question. Just for the other visitors bumping into this question and actually want to avoid it, see [this answer on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/145999/88802).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, cron scripts run parallelly, if you do not implement some
locking mechanism.

See [Quick-and-dirty way to ensure only one instance of a shell script is running at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at)  and  [Correct locking in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts) for possible solutions.

A simpler  way is to use `lockfile`, like in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/135/15241)
or the run-one package (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142002/generic-solution-to-prevent-a-long-cron-job-from-running-in-parallel/145999#145999))
- thanks to [gertvdijk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23363/gertvdijk) for suggesting it.

Comment: I think this is not the 'simplest' way. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/145999/88802) instead.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks for the hint, I improved my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [`whenjobs`](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/whenjobs/) which aims to be *"a powerful but simple cron replacement"*.  From [its manpage](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/whenjobs/whenjobs.txt):

> PRE FUNCTIONS
>
> Before a job runs, you can arrange that a "pre" function is called. This
>       function may decide not to run the job (by returning "false").
>
> One use for this is to prevent a particular job from running if there is
>       already an instance of the same job running:

```
job "only one"
pre (Whentools.one ())
every 10 seconds :
<<
  # Takes longer than 10 seconds to run, but 'Whentools.one ()'
  # will ensure only one is ever running.
  sleep 11
>>
```

(It also provides `Whentools.max n`, allowing `n` instances of the job to run.  By default, it works like Cron.)