# Getting empty data while reading text file and send read data to url by cURL in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, curl

I have text file called `read_data.txt` in `/var/www/html/` directory. I want to read data by `curl` while file contents will change. So I have created a `bash` script. It is reading data while the content is changed, and sends the content over mail. But instead of mail, I want to send that data to a specific url.

I am using the script below.

```
curl -d data=@/var/www/html/read_data.txt" http://domain.tld/testing_receive_data/index.php/check_data_controller/check_data
```

The above URL is receiving all post data and converting post array to JSON data by `json_encode` php function and logs it.

```
curl -d data=@/var/www/html/read_data.txt" http://domain.tld/testing_receive_data/index.php/check_data_controller/check_data
```

When I am running above code in the Linux shell, the JSON data is shown empty: `{"data"=[]}`

Answer (score 0):

I can think some possible causes.

1. Your program writing the file `read_data.txt`, it locked the file exclusively, so `curl` couldn't open the file. In this case you can easily test with another program to just dump the contents using `cat` or `tail`
2. While the file `read_data.txt` is getting more data, appending its contents, this is the point I'm not understanding why you didn't wait the file finished, the posted data is not complete, so your php program cannot translate them into json. Check your input from php side.

One possible solution is, rather than pouring the long&large data to the destination `read_data.txt`, you can just download it to a tmp file like `read_data.x4GwkQ.txt` and when you finishing the task, just rename(switch) it if you didn't lock it exclusively (`O_EXCL` in [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) function).

Or, just tie them up within an external lock file with `flock`.  [What Unix commands can be used as a semaphore/lock?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-unix-commands-can-be-used-as-a-semaphore-lock)