# Is this flock usage with if-else safe?

Tags: bash, shell-script, flock

I have two shell scripts that may be run in parallel but may also be run one at a time. Both scripts rely on an initial setup step that takes a while and can't be run by both at the same time.

To allow for parallel execution for the remainder, I've wrapped the setup step in control flow using [`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) based on [this recommendation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291/22607).

This *seems* to work fine, but I'm not sure if the if-else construct is fully safe. Are there any hidden issues here that I'm missing?

```bsh
set -euxo pipefail
(
    # Only run setup if we're the first to acquire the lock
    if flock -x -n 200 ; then
        # Time-consuming setup that can't be run in parallel
    else
        # Wait for the lock to be released and then continue, timeout on 600s
        flock -x -w 600 200;
    fi
) 200>/tmp/setup.lock

# Rest of the script that relies on setup being done
```

Comment: What shell is this using? Probably `bash`, right? "Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used with  care,  as
they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses internally."

Comment: If `flock` invocation did what you mention in comment that should be OK, however, what is `200>` use for ? is it a bad copy/paste ?

Comment: @Archemar No, it's redirecting file descriptor 200, set up by `flock`.

Comment: @Kusalananda This is bash, yes, forgot to note that, sorry. As for the 200, the example shown in the command's manpage uses that descriptor but I have no strong inclination for it, thanks for pointing that out. There's a question on the specific number [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551882/1470607), for anyone else interested.